# CURL-less HTTP request (returning array)

Tags: php

I am new in PHP and I am trying to access file of another website of mine. So on my web #1 I am trying to send a POST request like this:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://localhost/modul_cms/admin/api.php'; //Web #2

$data = array(
    "Action" => "getNewestRecipe",
    "Secret" => "61cbe6797d18a2772176b0ce73c580d95f79500d77e45ef810035bc738aef99c3e13568993f735eeb0d3c9e73b22986c57da60a0b2d6413c5dc32b764cc5897a",
    "User" => "joomla localhost",
);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $result;
if($result === FALSE){
    echo "Not working connection :(";
}else{
    echo "HOORAY!";
    var_dump($result);
}
```

And on my web #2 I have some kind of receiver I made. Now I need to return after selecting stuff from my database array of data. So I have code like this on my web #2:

```
<?php
 $action = isset( $_POST["action"] ) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
 $secret = isset( $_POST["secret"] ) ? $_POST["secret"] : "";
 $user = isset( $_POST["user"] ) ? $_POST["user"] : "";

 if(!empty($secret)){
  if(!empty($user)){

   switch($action){
     case 'getNewestRecipe':
      getNewestRecipe();
      break;

    case '':
      error();
      break;

    default:
      error();
      break;
   }
  }
}

/* *************** FUNCTIONS ************* */
function getNewestRecipe(){
  return array("msg" => "Here is your message!");
}
```

The problem is everything I get on my web #1 from the response is actually the echo I have there for knowing that the HTTP request reached something (so I've got the message "HOORAY!") but the

> var_dump($response)

has empty value (not NULL or something it's literally this):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\joomla30\templates\protostar\index.php:214:string '' (length=0)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Looks like an error occurs on web#2 and it generates a blank page because error reporting is disabled.

Comment: Or the POST data is not sent correctly and you don't even get into your `switch`. Looks like there is no output in that case. Maybe because you send "Secret" (uppercase) and check "secret"?

Comment: I am not sure even how to test this variant out but when I made mistake in array on my web#2 it returns me error to web#1 (error like: "expecting ',' not ';').

Comment: I am actually thinking if it's possible with `file_get_contents` to get only array because the whole web#2 is just php without echo or something it's only this switch with return.

Comment: file_get_contents is already without curl. If you go more low-level (fopen) you will only make your life harder. I'm actually quite certain your error is because the case difference.

Comment: Oh yes, you don't even `echo` it. That explains there is no output. Is it possible for you to just `include` the file and call the function in web#1? If you want to make it with curl/fget you will need to output it.

Comment: I don't know if it's quite safe to just `include` it. It should be some kind of custom API in final version. The Web #1 will be the web of someone else in the end so I don't know if it's good to include it.

Comment: And if I `echo` the array on Web#2 it's returning the pretty same thing just ' '.

Comment: You can't really `echo` an array. I'd try something like `echo json_encode(getNewestRecipe());`. And please make sure you actually get this far, e.g.: `case 'getNewestRecipe': echo 'here comes my data';`

Comment: So I actually tried this:
` case 'getNewestRecipe': echo "some data"; echo json_encode(getNewestRecipe()); getNewestRecipe(); break;` and it's still returning only ' '. I'll try to send HTTP request to some HTML page that might said at least if the connectivity is there.

Comment: I just added `<h1> Hello world </h1>` to my Web#2 and it's returning this `<h2>` so the problem is that I can't echo my array... But well this array will be every time different (depending on incoming POST request) so should I just echo my array as proper HTML content and then separate the values with php? Echo it like a table or just one big value with ' , ' as separator and then separate it?

Comment: If the `echo "some data";` didn't work you dont get into that code block. I suggest again to adjust the uppercase/lowercase difference. `echo json_encode(...)` should work fine and is actually a standardized data format, no need to build HTML.

Comment: Indeed this is definitely the problem. Thank you very much you saved me a lot of troubles looking for another solution and forgetting this HTTP request! Thank you.

Comment: Great. I summarized the problems of this rather long comment chain in an answer if you want to approve that and close the question. Also, building an API for this is fine. I only brought up the `include` approach because I thought you didn't want to `echo` it or use a HTTP request at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On web#1 you are sending *"Secret"*,*"User"*,*"Action"* in upper-case, but on web#2 you are accessing `$_POST['secret']` (lower-case). Because of this your code never gets to the call of `getNewestRecipe()` nor to your `error()` call, thus there is no content / a blank page, but also no error.

Also, you need to output the array your function returns in some way. 
An array cannot simply be `echo`d, so you need to serialize it. I suggest using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode): `echo json_encode(getNewestRecipe());`